# ACF plugin finding ID for image for PHP to display in page

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a wordpress site which is using the ACF plugin.

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

Using a plugin to allow for php in posts, I am trying to get the code to display an image using a shortcode given by ACF

What I have so far is

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( 'ID' ) ?>    This displays the image I need

<?php the_field('mobile_poster'); ?>    This displays the id for the image
```

What hasn't worked has been using

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( '[acf field="mobile_poster"] ') ?>
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Ben

Answer (score 0):

you can try for this **shortcode**:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[acf field="{$field_name}" post_id="{$post_id}"]' ) ?>
```

for Display ACF field Value

If you are trying to find image which have id of custom field the you can write this code

```
<?php 
$attachment_id = do_shortcode( '[acf field="{$field_name}"]' ) ;
wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id ); 
?>
```

Comment: Hi there, Sorry if I was unclear, I am able to display the value just fine, what I'm after is displaying an image based on the acf field value. But I'm unable to put the two bits of code together to make this work

Comment: means You are trying to find  wp_get_attachment_image() based on ACF field value?

Comment: wp_get_attachment_image( '421' ) displays an image based on an image ID (In this case ID=421)  /New Line/  <?php the_field('mobile_poster'); ?>  displays the ID number of the image using ACF fields (also ID=421)  /New Line/  Code works seperately but I wish to achieve is: "<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( ' <?php the_field('mobile_poster'); ?> ' ) ?> (in proper PHP of course) Hope this clears it up a little. Regards

Answer (score 0):

$attachment_id = get_field($field_name);
    wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id );

Note- Please make sure that you set the ACF image field return value to "Image Id" into the Wordpress back-end.